# Does hard disks order matter when Windows boots?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I had installed Windows on my hard disk 0 (and had another backup disk: 4TB DISK 1).

Several days ago, due to some reasons, I have changed cables of them, and now DISK 0 is my backup disk.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Does it matter for system speed? Because today I noticed Windows had 2-3 times increased boot time while I turned on my PC…   (My [MotherBoard model](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z77MAG45.html))

Or is that of another problem probably?

Comment: No; The order of the disks are not the reason you saw a performance increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is dependent on your motherboard, say if SATA port 0 has a different operating mode than SATA port 1 (or whatever ports you have them connected to) there would be a difference, but most likely they are all the same type and speed and the actual location the drive is connected to on the motherboard will not affect performance.

However, in your case there is a significant difference, your motherboard, an MSI Z77MA-G45, does indeed have different speed ports, it has two SATA-III (6Gbps) and four SATA-II (3Gbps) ports. SATA1 and SATA2 are 6Gbps ports and SATA3-6 are are 3Gbps ports. On page 1-22 of [your owners manual](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7759v1.0.zip), it clearly shows the different ports and speeds.

It would usually be advisable to have your boot device on SATA1 (the first port) and then the drive you want the fastest access to besides the boot drive to be connected to SATA2 as those are SATA-III ports (assuming you have SATA-III drives), after that drives could be connected to any port. Optical drives do not need to be connected to SATA-III ports as most do only support SATA-II anyway.

The startup speed in this case could very well be related to which port the hard disk is connected to, but would require more information to diagnose (that wasn't really the point of your question).

Comment: My motherboard is: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z77MAG45.html

to say more, the boot-up speed slowering I've noticed after I attached 3rd hard drive to PC.

btw..thanks, i cant upvote :(

Comment: @Selnomeria Ahh... So that motherboard does indeed have different speed ports, it has two SATA3 (6Gbps) and four SATA2 (3Gbps) ports. SATA1 and SATA2 are 6Gbps ports and SATA3-6 are are 3Gbps ports. http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7759v1.0.zip page 1-22 clearly shows the different ports and speeds. You should update your original question with that information.

Comment: aha, understood, thanks! when i have enough rep, I'll select answer.

Comment: i dont know what happens... I dont remember what was the order before I did changes to ports, but now I have connected 1 windows-boot drive into SATA1 and second drive into SATA3 and changed DVD from SATA1 to other..... the speed of pc is much slower than it was before that day, i remember well.. after that, my rendering times are 3 times slowered.. I have only changed the cables and pluged in different pins, but cant remember which ones I've displaced..

Comment: Initially I had 1TB+ 4TB +DVD drives in pc...  I dont know, but htat problems happened after adding the 4th drive (3TB drive).  I dont remember,but I've exchanged their lines and connected pins from one to another, while trying to place them, but seems I have did something ... at this moment, I have 1TB+4TB into SATA1-2 (6GBS), and the other two, in other pins, but still same sloweness.